# Overriden onKernelRequest event

Tags: php, events, symfony

In my Symfony2 application I'm getting an error when the page was not found (404) and I'm trying to use the isGranted method in my onKernelRequest event class.

So the question is: How can I check if the page was found or not in the event class?

// EDIT

Some code:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        $securityContext = $this->serviceContainer->get('security.context');

        /* The line below makes the script throw the following error:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in C:\xampp................ in C:\xampp\....\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php on line 144
        */
        if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you customize error pages?

Comment: By putting error.html.twig and error404.html.twig files in app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception

Comment: I've updated the question. Please re-read it

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use is_granted because the router runs before the firewall
see this [comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5225#issuecomment-7626407)

Just check token before executing isGranted:

```
if ( null !== $securityContext->getToken() && $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the exception. It works all perfectly without the event class above. I want to know why the line above is throwing an error.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea in which event I can perform my actions with the isGranted() method?

Comment: Just check token if is not empty before executing isGranted.